# Chromecast button missing on iOS 12 Xcode 10

Tags: chromecast, xcode10, ios12

We're using Google Chromecast SDK (google-cast-sdk) on our iOS Application over a year, but when I updated to iOS 12 and Xcode 10 button has disappeared.

Does anyone face the same issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem and solution

> Xcode 10 Warning: If developing using Xcode 10 and targeting iOS
>   devices running iOS 12 or higher, the "Access WiFi Information"
>   capability is required in order to discover and connect to Cast
>   devices

You need to ensure that the **Access WiFi Information** switch in the Capabilities section of the target is set to **On**.

[image: Access WiFi Information]

That's all you need!